# Struggling to write assert for Fortran

Tags: fortran, c-preprocessor, assert

I am trying to write assert command for a Fortran program, but the whole thing is driving me nuts.  Allow me to show you what have up to now:

File: Assert.h:

```
#define Assert(X) call Handle_Assert(.not.(X), #X, __FILE__, __LINE__)
```

File: Check_Assert.F90:

```
#include "Assert.h"

program Check_Assert
use Assert_Mod

Assert(1>2)

end program
```

And finally the file: Assert_Mod.F90:

```
module Assert_Mod

contains

  subroutine Handle_Assert(fail, text, file, line)
  implicit none
  logical      :: fail
  character(*) :: text
  character(*) :: file
  integer      :: line

  if(fail) then
    print *, 'Assertion ',       text,   &
             ' failed in file ', file,   &
             ' at line ',        line,   &
             '.'
    stop
  end if

  end subroutine

end module
```

When I compile it with:

```
gfortran -c Assert_Mod.F90
gfortran -o check Assert_Mod.o Check_Assert.F90
```

I get the following error message:

```
Check_Assert.F90:6:31:

  6 | Assert(1>2);
    |                               1
Error: Syntax error in argument list at (1)
```

If I do exactly the same thing with Intel Fortran, all works fine and program gives expected output:

```
Assertion 1>2 failed in file Check_Assert.F90 at line            6 .
```

￼
Does anyone have a clue what is going on with GNU Fortran?  Why can't it swallow the assert in the way I defined it, and in the way it works for Intel?

Any help or hint would be appreciated.

*Cheers*

Comment: Which version of gfortran did you use? Did you have a look at the preprocessed output? Did you try `.false.` ?

Comment: Please post also your workaround.

Comment: I am struggling to break lines in comments, I will post is as the answer to my own question.

Answer (score 3):

It has to do with the second argument of your macro `#X` and how the Fortran expression is cast into a string. If you remove that from your macro and subroutine definition you should be good to go

```
module Assert_Mod

contains
    
    subroutine Handle_Assert(fail, file, line)
        logical, intent(in)      :: fail
        character(*), intent(in) :: file
        integer, intent(in)      :: line

        if(fail) then
        print *, ' failed in file ', file,   &
                 ' at line ',        line,   &
                 '.'
        stop
        end if

    end subroutine Handle_Assert
    
end module

program Check_Assert
use Assert_Mod
#define Assert(X) call Handle_Assert(.not.(X), __FILE__, __LINE__)

Assert(1>2)

end program
```

On a related note, I would urge against using preprocessor macros to define an `assert` function (even though I do the same sometimes). Here is an example for floating point assertions that you can draw inspiration from: https://scivision.github.io/fortran2018-examples/sourcefile/assert.f90.html
and here is a more involved error framework which also reports the stack trace: https://fortran-lang.discourse.group/t/fortran-error-handling-including-stacktrace-generation/4648

There are also a lot of other assertion/testing libraries in Fortran that might be better suited for your case.

Answer (score 2):

OK folks, thanks for the attention, I managed to work around as this:

```
#if __GFORTRAN__ == 1
#  define Assert(X) call Handle_Assert(.not.(X), "X", __FILE__, __LINE__)
#else
#  define Assert(X) call Handle_Assert(.not.(X), #X, __FILE__, __LINE__)
#endif
```

I am not sure how elegant you find it or how robust this is, but works as expected.